# Excel VBA: Push data from excel file A to another excel file B

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to push a single cell data from excel spreadsheet A to another excell spreadsheet B. This two excel spreadsheets are network copy (Eg. www.stackoverflowA.com and www.stackoverflowB.com)

Details:

Excel spreadsheet A's cell "B5" contains the data that i wished to be pushed to Excel spreadsheet B.

Excel spreadsheet B's cell "B3" is where i wished the data to be pulled from Excel spreadsheet A

On top of the above requirement, i would like to have a condition check whether Excel spreadsheet A's cell "B5" and Excel spreadsheet B's cell "B3 dates tally with one another.

I would really appreciate all helps to solve this. Thank you all!

Code (what i have tried out so far but it is having some error and i have no idea how to add in the condition checker into this code):

```
Private Sub TestPushValue2()
    Dim IntlStatusBook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim url As String

    url = "www.stackoverflowA.com"

    ' make active workbook is the target
    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    ' get the IntlStatus workbook
    Set IntlStatusWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(url)

    ' copy data from IntlStatus to target workbook
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = IntlStatusWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    sourceSheet.Range("B5").Value = targetSheet.Range("B3")Value 

    ' Close IntlStatus workbook
    IntlStatusWorkbook.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call TestPushValue2
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming that you have Excel Book1 (a workbook file) opened with source data in the cell B5, then in the second file Book2, cell B3 you can put a worksheet formula like: =[Book1]Sheet1!$B$5. Hope this will help. Regards,

Comment: Would your macro need to open both files? What would the macro need to return if they don't match? SO is not a code outsourcing platform, you need to post what you have tried and where you are having errors/difficulty.

Comment: I would need the marco to open the two files in order to facilate the export and importing of data. Rest assure that i am not trying to do code outsourcing here. I'm new with VBA and tried a few ways but couldnt get it working.

Answer (score 0):

From Excel's Help. Note it pulls rather than pushes.

Create a link between cells in different workbooks

Open both the workbook that will contain the link (called the destination workbook), and the workbook that contains the data you want to link to (called the source workbook). 
In the destination workbook, click Save . 
Select a cell or cells you want to link from. 
If you are creating a new formula, type = (an equal sign). 
If you are entering the link elsewhere in the formula, type the operator or function that you want to precede the link.

On the Window menu, click the name of the source workbook, and then click the worksheet that contains the cells you want to link to.

Select the cells you want to link to. 
Complete the formula. When you finish entering the formula, press ENTER.